# Caching Problem: Different Domain for Backend and Frontend Typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i have an issue with the caching of typo3. The scenario is i have the base: www.domain.com and another base variant cache.domain.com.  It seems like the cache tables are only cleared per domain e.g. if i’m in the backend of chache.domain.com it will only clear the db entries for that particular domain. The cf_cache_hash table has still content. After i clear the cache in the www backend the table is empty.

Is this behavior correct? And if so how can i clear with one backend everything?
Many thanks for any suggestions and advice
Kind regards
Jan

Comment: How do you clear the cache in the backend? By "right-clicking in the page tree › Clear cache of this page" or "Clear cache › Flush frontend caches"/"Flush all caches" from the header menu?

Comment: I'm using the "Flush frontend caches".

Comment: Did you get rid of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this. Clearing frontend caches will clear for all domains.